# Scan Int and Char in Java

Tags: java

Im trying to do a java script that can convert hex to binary. 
What the script does, is that it prompts the user for a hex input and comes up with the binary equivalent output.

Im having issues as i dont know how to set the parameters for the scanner input, as a hex can both be an Int and Char.

I know what i've done here is wrong.. can you by any chance tell me how to do this correct?

i just stripped out the part in question of my script. :-)

```
char hex;       
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a hex digit: ");
hex = in.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char hex;       
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a hex digit: ");
hex = in.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("binary is "+new BigInteger(hex+"", 16).toString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need. Use string then convert it.

```
BigInteger.toString(radix) 




static String hexToBin(String s) {
   return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: ty for the quick answer! 

however do i have to convert it to a string if i only want to prompt 1 digit? i only want the script to be able to convert the value from 0 - F :-)